# My terminal on osx 10.11.6 will not accept `[` character

Tags: terminal

Every time I type it the terminal flashes but doesn't insert it. If I paste in a command that has a `[` it will paste everything except the `[`'s

This has been happening before I updated to 10.11, but has become a massive issue, I can't use `jq` at all because of it.

I also have the same issue with iTerm2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have found the cause in my `.inputrc`

```
[[ $- = *i* ]] && bind TAB:menu-complete
```

I don't know why it's the cause of the problem but it was resolved by removing this, and to be honest I am not even sure what the reason for this being there was

if anyone knows the reason this causes it please feel free to answer and I will accept that answer over this

Comment: It's because .inputrc is not a bash script, so conditionals like `[[ $- = *i* ]] &&` don't work. Instead, it just looks for things like `keysequence:function/macro`. In this case (as I understand it), it's going to treat "`[[ $- = *i* ]] && bind TAB`" as the key sequence to define, so whenever you type "`[`" it thinks you're trying to start this sequence. Then, when you type something other than the rest of the sequence, it gets confused.